# Remove 'start-line' and 'end-line' of Timeline (v-timeline) Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to remove the 'start-line' and 'end-line' of the timeline (v-timeline) Vuetify component?
I just can change the color but I don't know how to remove it.

I want to remove the line which marked with a green arrow, the blue arrow is the expected result :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit hacky. But I found that adding:

```
.v-timeline::before {
    top: 55px;
    height: calc(100% - 110px)
}
```

seemed to do the trick for me :)

Comment: This worked for me with a little tweaking of the values to account for the `dense` flag on the `v-timeline`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a slightly more dynamic way:

```
// template
<span :class="isLast ? 'clipTimeline' : ''">
    <v-timeline>
        <v-timeline-item />
    </v-timeline>
</span>

// css
.v-timeline::before {
  top: 20px // value depends upon individual case
}
.clipTimeline .v-timeline::before {
  height: 0;
}
```

> isLast

is true if it is the end of the list.